# VS Code linking launch configuration to commands from command pallete

Tags: json, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to make a VS Code extension where the launch.json would have launch configurations that link to the command palette.

Specifically, I have registered commands using `vscode.commands.registerCommand("CommandA")`. Is there a way to make it so that the launch.json would direct to "CommandA"?

EDIT: I basically want [image] to run a command from package.json

Comment: The only way to get any command to show up in the Command Palette is to have it in the extension's `package.json` as a contributed command.  So you would have to read the configurations and update the `package.json` with a command for each.  Which would require a reload.  You can look at the `Command Alias` extension that I wrote for one approach.

Comment: `lauch.json` is for all stuff happening in the terminal (debuggers). How do you think it is possible for a CLI command to execute some VSC command. Maybe you can monitor the terminal content in an extension and execute the command by the extension

Comment: you can add arguments to the launch that uses the `${input}` variable, this can call any VSC command and the result of the command will be the variable result

Comment: @rioV8 There is a command `vscode.debug.startDebugging()` that can be used to start any configuration.  I use it extensively in the `Launch Configs` extension.  So that part is easy.  I just don't bother to make them into `package.json` commands which would be easy too - see `Command Alias` extension.  I fire launch configs from keybindings, but could just as well be from the Command Palette if I choose to make them into package.json contributed commands.  So it is definitely doable.

Comment: @Mark yes, going from `launch.json` to `package.json` is doable, but the main problem I have right now is converting `package.json` contributed commands into `launch.json`. For example, is it possible for me to call the `package.json` contributed command "CommandA" in `launch.json` configuration?

Comment: Yes, you can call a command whatever you want - it has a descriptive name as well as the actual `myExtension.myCommand` name.  You would "probably" have to give them each a formal command name like `myExtension.launch<someConfigName>` with its own descriptive name.  Your extension could create all the commands based off the configuration name.  So it would essentially parse the each command name to get the right config name.  That is because triggering the commands from the Command Palette will not provide any arguments.  One reason why I went with keybindings - you can pass args.

Comment: The descriptive name is what the user sees in the Command Palette.

Comment: @Mark Sorry, when I meant by calling the `package.json` contributed command "CommandA" in `launch.json` was more about can I run a contributed command without having to use keybindings or the Command Palette. Instead, is it possible for the contributed command to show up Launch Configurations button?

A basic example would be that when the user starts debugging (by pressing F5), can I program that to say Hello World instead? I want to do this without changing the key bindings if possible. Also I would not like to use an executable file if possible.

Answer (score -1):

You can use have a launch configuration run a registered command from the command palette using command variables.

Comment: It would be useful to show how.